# and or handling in typeorm query builder

Tags: sql, node.js, typeorm

How to handle and or in typeorm query builder

Here is a simple query:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE (id = 1  or id = 2) and status = 2
```

What I tried so far is:

```
const result = await connection
  .getRepository(Users)
  .createQueryBuilder("users")
  .select(['name'])
  .where("id", 1)
  .orWhere("id", 2)
  .andWhere("status", 2)
  .getMany();
```

The above solution is not providing me a correct record.

Can anyone help me with the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is evaluating those conditions one by one, rather than executing the `OR` and then the `AND` against the result of the previous operation. You need to use brackets (`import {Brackets} from 'typeorm'`).

```
const result = await connection
  .getRepository(Users)
  .createQueryBuilder("users")
  .select(['name'])
  .where("status", 2)
  .andWhere(
    new Brackets((qb) => {
      qb.orWhere("id", 1);
      qb.orWhere("id", 2);
    }),
  )
  .getMany();
```